# fs writes file in wrong location

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to use writefile, but for some reason it does it outside of ./events folder..

im trying to use fs like,

```
        fs.writeFile("./level.json", JSON.stringify(storage), (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

xp.js is trying to write the level.json in the same folder.

[image: The files being used.]

Comment: Yes, that's what `./` means :) "Same folder". Try `"./events/level.json"`

Comment: @JeremyThille

Cannot find module './events/level.json'

Im not trying to use the json file thats outside of the events folder.

Comment: `__dirname + "/events/level.json"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `./` references the current working directory, so wherever you ran the script from.  If you'd like the path to reference the same folder where the currently running js file is, use `__dirname` instead like so:

```js
fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/level.json`, JSON.stringify(storage), (err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Source: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-__dirname-and-in-node-js/#:~:text=The%20__dirname%20in%20a,It%20works%20similar%20to%20process](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-__dirname-and-in-node-js/#:%7E:text=The%20__dirname%20in%20a,It%20works%20similar%20to%20process).

Answer (score 0):

To be more consistent across different architectures I suggest you to use path module.
So in your case:

```
fs.writeFile(require('path').resolve('events', 'level.json'), JSON.stringify(storage), (err) => {
  console.log(err)
});
```